# How to add update, delete and view button in my php rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add "update", "delete" and "view" in the other page button in the right side of the table rows of my php table. Please help me to add it. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbname');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Failed to connect: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$results);

echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
    echo '</tr>';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['Lastname'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: wait? how to add update delete and view buttons? or add update delete and view functionalities? thats a chunk of code, too broad

Comment: Add this tag and inside create a button or 2 button (  echo '<td><button type="button">Edit</button><button type="button">Add</button></td>';)

Comment: I mean, in that .php file, table has 3 button at the right side. The Update, Delete and View. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<tr>';
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
        echo "<th>Actions</th>";
echo '</tr>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Lastname'].'</td>';
    echo "<td>
             <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Update </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteRow('<?php echo $row[id] ?>');"> Delete </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">View </a>
         </td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

You should use jquery/Ajax for delete. It is better option.

For delete write this function: Need to add min jquery file

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function deleteRow(id)
{
     $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'id' : id,
                },
                success : function(response) { 
                  alert('Record deleted');
                },
                error : function() {                                                
                },
                complete : function() {
                }

            });
}
</script>
```

write your delete record code in 'delete.php'.

This is one option. You can do this in more good and specific way. Everything to say here is not possible for me.

for view you can do this in two ways.

1) If you want to display in same format, redirect it on self page and put condition like.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])
{
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $query = "SELECT * FROM table where id=$id";
}
else
{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
}
```

2) If you want in different format, Do same thing in view.php select only that record.

One simple thing i want to ask what is the need for view? when it is already in table above.

For Update write in your update.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])
{
         $id = $_POST['id'];
         $query = "SELECT * FROM table where id=$id";
}
```

and set form action

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
```

fetch value of above result in input box like and also fetch id as hiiden field:

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' value='<?php echo $row['firstname'];  ?>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>
```

and for update you can go like:

```
 if(isset($_POST['firstname'] && isset($_POST['lastname'] ) // Here you can use your any required field  
    { 
             //Your update logic go here like:
             $id = $_POST['id'];
             $query = "UPDATE table SET firstname=$_POST['firstname'] where id=$id"; // Your whole update query.
    }
```

Comment: Sir How can I add ajax loader while I'm deleting or editing the table. :) God bless and thanks sir. :)

Comment: What you mean by ajax loader ? And there should not ajax in edit. For delete I edited my answer just for sample.

Comment: It's okay sir, I'll try when I arrive at home. :D

Comment: Sir another question, when I click the "view.php" button that you've made, of course it will redirect to "view.php" page. How can I view the table information from the table where I clicked the view button. How can I get the information from that table rows to the "view.php" page? I can't figured it out sir. :)

Comment: Because sir. In view.php, I want to print that information from that table. I want to create receipt form. That table, is the customer's information. When I click the view button, it will redirect to "View.php" for me to print that information. :) Sir sorry sir, I asked a lot. Because I have no internet connection at home. When I arrived, I will try your codes above. Hope it will function well. :)

Comment: Sir what about the "update.php"? :) God bless and thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0):

i see some mistake in your code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$results);
```

should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

try this

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
    echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
    echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
    echo "<th></th>";
echo '</tr>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Firstname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['Lastname'].'</td>';
    echo "<td>
             <input type='submit' value='update'>
             <input type='submit' value='delete'>
             <input type='submit' value='view'>
         </td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Without form element those submits don't do much. I think it would be better to make links with parameters like this -- `<a href="delete?id=5>delete</a>`. Only problem is with update.

Comment: i think the only prob that he wants to solve is how to insert a command buttons on each right side of the datas, yup i agree it is more simpler to use links than forms :DDDDD

Comment: What do you mean sir. :)

Comment: i am quite unsure about your question, do you want to achieve a table structure which consist of buttons at the right side or a table structure that consists a button at the right side together with the function of each?

Comment: The second sir "Table structure that consists of button on the right side with functionalities" When I clicked update, the information in the table will update. When I clicked delete, the information will be deleted sir. And when I clicked view, the information of the table will appear on the "View.php" page. Thank you sir. :)

Comment: read and watch this link [link]http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/12/php-and-mysql-crud-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks sir for this. :D God bless. What country are you from bro?

Comment: im from PH, i see that your new in php..well me too

Answer (score 0):

Try this functions:

```
<?php
Class Db {
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    function insert($table,array $data) {
        $fields = '';$values = '';

        foreach($data as $col => $value) {
            $fields.= $col.",";
        }

        foreach($data as $col => $value) {
            $values.= "'".replace_str($value)."',";
        }

        $fields = substr($fields,0,-1);
        $values = substr($values,0,-1);

        if(!$query = mysqli_query($this->connection,"insert into ".$table."(".$fields.") values(".$values.")")) {
            HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\query:$query");
        }

        return $query;
    }

    function update($table, array $data, $where) {
        $fields = '';$values = '';

        foreach($data as $col => $value) {
            $values.= $col."='".replace_str($value)."',";
        }

        $values = substr($values,0,-1);

        if(!$query = mysqli_query($this->connection,"update ".$table." set ".$values." where ".$where)) {
            HandleDBError("Error updating data to the table\query:$query");
        }

        return $query;
    }

    function delete($table, $where = '') {
        if ($where)
            return mysqli_query($this->connection,"delete from ".$table." where ".$where);

        return mysqli_query($this->connection,"delete from ".$table);
    }

    function get($strQuery) {
        if(!$query = mysqli_query($this->connection,$strQuery)) {
            HandleDBError("Error inserting data to the table\query:$query");
        }
        $data = [];
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

?>